# VSTO type ThisWorkbook cannot be found

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO excel plugin that I'm upgrading from VSTOR 2005 SE to VSTOR 3.0 (using Excel 2007 and VS 2008 - I know, I know, it's hardly an upgrade).

I've gone through the conversion wizard in Visual Studio and changed my deployment process to use the .vsto manifest file instead of the old .application file.  The plugin is a document-level customisation and I've written a small utility that uses the ServerDocument class to add the customisation to a given document.  Updating this to VSTOR 3.0 required some fiddling with references (the ServerDocument class has been moved to its own assembly).  This now completes successfully.

When I try to open the document in Excel, I get an error.  The full thing is reproduced below, but the relevant bit seems to be this:

```
The type "Symbols.ExcelPlugin.ThisWorkbook" could not be found
```

The thing is I've looked (using ildasm) and the ThisWorkbook type jolly well is in that assembly.

So I assume that the problem is that that type can't be loaded.  Does anyone have any ideas on why?

```
The customization assembly could not be found or could not be loaded.
You can still edit and save the document.  Contact your administrator or the author of this document for further assistance.

Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created.


************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: Customization could not be loaded because the application domain could not be created. ---> System.ArgumentException: The type "Symbols.ExcelPlugin.ThisWorkbook" could not be found in assembly "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\P0TR8LGM.WYQ\0YE3VH3V.B1Z\symb..vsto_d0ae671434bad267_0001.0000_507c1dd17bbfdc47\Symbols.dll"
   at System.AddIn.Hosting.AddInStore.FindAddIn(Type hostViewOfAddIn, String pipelineRootFolderPath, String addInFilePath, String addInTypeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.AddInStoreExtensions.FindAddIn(AddInInformation addInInformation, String pipelinePath, Type hostAddInView, SegmentConstraints[] segmentConstraints)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String documentFullLocation, String documentName, String assemblyLocation, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String documentFullLocation, String documentName, String assemblyLocation, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.ICreateCustomizationDomain.CreateCustomizationDomain(String documentFullLocation, String documentName, String assemblyLocation, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5472 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v9.0
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.21022.123
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v9.0.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5420 built by: Win7SP1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.AddIn
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5446 built by: Win7SP1GDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.AddIn/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.AddIn.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v9.0
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.21022.123
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v9.0.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v9.0
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.21022.123
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v9.0.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.21022.123
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.AddIn.Contract
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.5420 built by: Win7SP1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.AddIn.Contract/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.AddIn.Contract.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be because the upgrade wizard hadn't completely upgraded the solution; there was still a reference to `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Office2003.targets` in the csproj file - changing this to refer to `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Office2007.targets` fixed the problem.